Gradle Project Sync Failed. Cause: zip END header not found
My android project was working fine until I started an emulator for android tablet.
Since then I was not able sync my project. I tried uninstalling android studio and pulled my working github repository. But issue remains same

Cause: zip END header not found
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.MetaDataParseException: Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta10/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta10.pom

    * Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Naturo'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:84)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$500(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:756)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$2(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$10(StateTransitionController.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:381)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:65)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at ontroller.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at  ... 193 more

gradle.properties
properties=
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true

gradle-wrapper.properties
# Gradle properties for the wrapper

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

settings.gradle.kts
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Naturo"
include(":app")


build.gradle.kts (Project level)

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinKsp) apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

build.gradle.kts (app level)
        plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlinKsp) // Correct use of KSP plugin for annotation processing
    }
    
    android {
        namespace = "com.minimalapps.naturo"
        compileSdk = libs.versions.compileSdk.get().toInt()
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "com.minimalapps.naturo"
            minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt()
            targetSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                isMinifyEnabled = true
                proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                    "proguard-rules.pro"
                )
            }
        }
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        // Core app dependencies
        implementation(libs.core.ktx)
        implementation(libs.appcompat)
        implementation(libs.material)
        implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
        implementation(libs.recyclerview)
        implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
        implementation(libs.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
        implementation(libs.coroutines.android)
        implementation(libs.room.runtime)
        implementation(libs.room.ktx)
        ksp(libs.room.compiler)
        implementation(libs.datastore.preferences)
    
        // Testing dependencies
        testImplementation(libs.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    }


You can manually download the gradle-8.9-bin.zip file from the URL and replace the corrupted file in the wrapper/dists directory.

@liaifat85 can you provide the specific path? Is it only issue with gradle? I did install android studio multiple times and pulled working repository from github.

In windows, usually the path is C:\Users<Username>.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.9-bin<hash> . The error zip END header not found indicates the downloaded ZIP file is incomplete or corrupt. Even if you reinstall,  it may reuse the existing Gradle cache and the problem may remain the same .

@liaifat85 I have deleted entire android studio including all traces, gradle folder and pulled working git repo still issue remains same.
